# Serverless MalformedPolicyDocument error - Resource must be in ARN format or "*"

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have the following configuration for Serverless Lambda with IAM configuration and I get the following error: `MalformedPolicyDocument error - Resource must be in ARN format or "*"` for the value I pass under this config:

```
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            -  'kafka-cluster:Connect'
            -  'kafka-cluster:DescribeTopic'
            -  'kafka-cluster:DescribeGroup'
            -  'kafka-cluster:ReadData'
            -  'kafka-cluster:AlterGroup'
            -  'kafka-cluster:DescribeClusterDynamicConfiguration'
          Resource: ${env.KAFKA_CLUSTER_ARN}
```

The value for is `arn:aws:kafka:us-west-2:111111111111:cluster/kafka-cluster-test/6ebf68e8-ad47-47af-8c41-5801c095ab72-1` which is configured in the env config files.

Using Serverless `2.72.2`

Please advise what I'm not configuring properly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred due to improperly calling `dotenv` using `env.` instead of `env:`